# I am not able re-render the state once it is updated

Tags: reactjs

I am not able to render the data once the state is updated.

but I get the data on the console once I submit

I am using ContextApi

[Project link](https://codesandbox.io/s/exciting-haze-tf9cy)

**Data**

```
<div>
      {datas.map(data => {
        return (
          <button
            key={data.id}
            onClick={() => handleData(data)}
            className="btn btn-primary m-4"
          >
            {data.title}
          </button>
        );
      })}
      <DetailData />
    </div>
```

**detail of a particular Data**
**which contains an input box to where the user will write a comment, and the comment will be showing above

**

```
return (
    <>
      {DetailData == null ? (
        <></>
      ) : (
        <div className="card mx-4">
          <div className="card-body">
            <h5 className="card-title">{DetailData.title}</h5>
            <h6 className="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted">
              Id: {DetailData.id}
            </h6>
            <p className="card-text">{DetailData.Description}</p>
          </div>
          <hr />
          comment:{DetailData.comment}

          <CommentBox bid={DetailData.id} cm={DetailData.comment} />
        </div>
      )}
    </>
  );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make this changes in your ContextApi, find Added this line comment :
by the other means, you need to update DetailData after submit

```
import React, { Component, createContext } from "react";
export const Contx = createContext();

export class ConProvider extends Component {
  state = {
    name: "",
    datas: [
      {
        id: 1,
        title: "Reactjs",
        Description:
          "React is a JavaScript library for building user interfaces. It is maintained by Facebook and a community of individual developers and companies. React can be used as a base in the development of single-page or mobile applications, as it is optimal for fetching rapidly changing data that needs to be recorded.",
        comment: []
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        title: "Bootstrap",
        Description:
          "Bootstrap is a free and open-source CSS framework directed at responsive, mobile-first front-end web development. It contains CSS- and JavaScript-based design templates for typography, forms, buttons, navigation and other interface components",
        comment: []
      }
    ],
    DetailData: null
  };

  handleData = data => {
    this.setState({
      DetailData: data
    });
  };
  handleInput = e => {
    this.setState({
      [e.target.name]: e.target.value
    });
  };

  handleSubmit = async commentid => {
    const com = this.state.name;
    const updateComment = await this.state.datas.map(c => {
      if (c.id === commentid) {
        return {
          ...c,
          comment: [...c.comment, com]
        };
      } else {
        return c;
      }
    });

    // Added this line
    const dData = await updateComment.filter(c => c.id === commentid);

    this.setState({
      datas: updateComment,
      name: "",
      DetailData: dData[0] // Added this line
    });

  };

  render() {
    return (
      <Contx.Provider
        value={{
          ...this.state,
          handleData: this.handleData,
          handleInput: this.handleInput,
          handleSubmit: this.handleSubmit
        }}
      >
        {this.props.children}
      </Contx.Provider>
    );
  }
}
```